# Self-assessment map

Tags: web-app

There is the system the purpose of which is to assess yourself in various areas and skills related to those areas. On the x-axis are areas, and on the y-axis are their skills (see the attachment).

Each skill could be marked as Foundation, Advanced and Mastery.

So far, it's not clear what exactly is wrong with the current system, if at all.

**At this point, the goal is to find better ways (or just alternatives) of rendering the same experience.**

Would appreciate UX as well as UI suggestions, any relevant links to existing systems, researches, etc. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The grid looks great but I feel like it would be hard to fill out. I would suggest using a form for when the user needs to complete the assessment and use the awesome grid you designed for when viewing or sharing the form.

[image: Example form layout]